# Excel VBA copy string in column A to B in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy a string in column A to B on the same row? If possible I would like to use a custom string in the code to look for and copy from the same row from column A to B.

```
 (not real code, just for example purpose) Something like _
 select.column.A.copy.text.find (""Test:"") to column B on the same row.
```

String can be on any row.

---

**Input:**

**Column A**

""Test":"

---

**Output:**

**Column B**

""Test":"

---

[image: SCreen]

Comment: Something like `Range("B1") = Range("A1")` ?

Comment: Yes but then only for a specific string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below sub. You may need to adjust codes for your actual sheet data range.

```
Sub CopyAtoB()
Dim lrw As Long
Dim rng As Range

lrw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & lrw)
        rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng
    Next

End Sub
```

> Edit: Based on comment try below sub.

```
Sub CopyAtoB()
Dim lrw As Long
Dim rng As Range

lrw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & lrw)
        If (InStr(1, LCase(rng), "username") > 0) Or _
           (InStr(1, LCase(rng), "password") > 0) Or _
           (InStr(1, LCase(rng), "id") > 0) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: *If possible I would like to use a custom string in the code to look for and copy from the same row from column A to B.* How does your answer address this request?

Comment: Hi @Harun24HR I do appreciate the answer, but as Tom Brunberg says, how could I apply the above in your code?

Comment: Can you please make an example of custom string look for?

Comment: Yes the custom string to look for should be "Username": "", and "Password": "", and "ID": "", only these 3 strings must be copied to colum A (right now everything gets copied)

Comment: Hi Harun this does not work I think because there are already quotation marks in the words themselves so in fact you get ""username": ""," and ""password": ""," and ""id": "","

Comment: No issue with quotation mark. Can you share a sample file via google drive or dropbox or one drive?

Comment: I have added a screenshot, so username, password  and id most me copied to column B on the same row.

Comment: I tried running your code, but nothing seems to happen :O

Comment: Oh wait it works, I tried using Username instead of username